# what are the metatable details in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

What to know list of metadata tables details in snowflake.
in oracle we have user_tables..etc
like oracle what to know metadata table in snowflake.

Eg: select *From user_tables
where table_name='EMP';

Answer (score 0):

Metadata is stored in
[Information Schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html):

> The Snowflake Information Schema (aka “Data Dictionary”) consists of a set of system-defined views and table functions that provide extensive metadata information about the objects created in your account.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFROMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMP';
```

Comment: Also, Snowflake has SHOW commands that can come in handy, as well.